# As of 2021, what is the latest record for lowest temperature?

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, low-temperature-physics

From what I understand in this [article](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn18541-what-happens-at-absolute-zero/), absolute zero(0 kelvin) is an impossible task.

They state that the lowest temperature achieved in the laboratory was 0.1 nanokelvin.

> The lowest temperature ever recorded was back here on Earth in a laboratory. In September 2003, scientists at the Massachusetts Institute of Technology announced that they’d chilled a cloud of sodium atoms to a record-breaking 0.45 nanokelvin. Earlier, scientists at the Helsinki University of Technology in Finland achieved a temperature of 0.1 nanokelvin in a piece of rhodium metal in 1999. However, this was the temperature for just one particular type of motion – a quantum property called nuclear spin – not the overall temperature for all possible motions.

As of 2021, what is the lowest temperature achieved in an experiment (laboratory)?

Comment: Not answering your question, but related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature